# Simple linear functional optimization

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, linear-programming

Let's say we have smooth function $\phi:[a,b]\to \Bbb R$ and we would like to find a measurable function $f$ such that $c\leq f(x) \leq d$ for all $x\in[a,b]$, $\int_a^b f(x)\phi(x)\mathrm dx = e$ and it maximizes $\int_a^b xf(x)\phi(x)\mathrm dx$. Is there an explicit solution in this case? It reminds of linear programming, but in somewhat infinite-dimensional setting.

Comment: I wonder if a similar approach can be used to linear programming (i.e. Lagrangian multipliers), but perhaps using techniques from variadic calculus. For instance, maybe using the functional derivative instead of the typical derivative?

Answer (score 3):

Due to the inequality constraints, the problem is solvable.
From Lagrange multiplier theory, we get the following necessary and sufficient optimality conditions: $f\in L^1$ is optimal iff there is $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ such that
$$
\int_a^b (x-\lambda)\phi(x)( g(x)-f(x))dx \ge0
$$
for all $L^1$-functions $g$ with $c\le g\le d$.
If $\lambda$ is known and $\phi(x)\ne0$ almost everywhere, this inequality determines $f=f_\lambda$ as a function of $\lambda$.

Together with the condition 
$$
\int_a^b f(x)\phi(x)dx=e
$$
you end up with a non-smooth system in the parameter $\lambda$: Find $\lambda$ such that
$$
\int_a^b f_\lambda(x)\phi(x)dx=e.
$$
It might be possible to calculate the solution explicitly for special choices of the parameter.

Comment: It seems to me, just getting inspiration from discrete version of the problem, that in case $c = 0$ I need to have $f = d$ for all $x\geq \lambda$ and $0$ otherwise, perhaps that applies to general $c$ as well.

Comment: Yes, that is true: however, $\lambda$ still needs to be determined from the integral equation constraint.